# Exporting documentation on a Confluence Page as JIRA issues

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-rest-api

We have a simple text based confluence page that we use for monthly maintenance related tasks.  I was wondering if there's an automated way to create either a single JIRA task with subtasks, or a group of JIRA tasks from that page.

I expect that I may have to write a macro for this in Java? Unless someone is aware of an existing tool that already does this?

Can I use the `jira-api` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this, but I used Jenkins to run this periodically. Of course you could simply write a script and run it in a cron job.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Write a bash script to read your confluence page. You can use the confluence REST API to get the contents of the page. https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#content-getContent
2. Use JQ (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the JSON that the Confluence REST API returns. You will need to do some additional parsing of the content itself, since your confluence page is a text (unstructured) page.
3. Once you have the content from confluence, and have figured out what the jira issue will be, you can create it with the Jira REST API. https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-createIssue

Both these REST APIs can be called with simple curl commands from your bash script.

I have created a blog on something similar:
http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/05/jira-confluence-3.html

There is some code in github too, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Confluence API](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/) to extract the page content and then the [JIRA API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) to create a new issue.

Confluence also has the capability to [create a JIRA issue in a page](https://dev.obss.com.tr/confluence/display/ATLKB/Creating+Jira+issue+in+Confluence). You could take the approach of creating an issue to store your monthly maintenance and then linking to it in a Confluence page. Then the users update the JIRA issue via Confluence rather than having to do it in JIRA. In effect you would be storing the information in one place (JIRA) but displaying it in two places: JIRA and Confluence.